# Open a MS Access db protected

Tags: vba, ms-access, passwords

I have an issue coding on MS Access.

Here the code I have, easy code, to control a button to import data (from a form in MS Access to another MS Access DB). The macro is located in a DB protected by a pw.
After few tests I am not able to find the good script to open and fill the pw. The pw must be included in the script to have an automatic process. (The username thing is properly sorted with a Public function).

MS Access 365 MSO 16.0 64bits Version 2108

```
Private Sub Command35_Click()
    Dim AppAccess As Access.Application
    Set AppAccess = GetObject("C:\Users\" & GetUserName & "\Databases\DB Friends.accdb")
    AppAccess.Visible = False
    AppAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro "Mcr_M_NewFriends"
    AppAccess.Quit
    Me.Command35.BackColor = RGB(255, 124, 128)
    MsgBox "New friends data imported"
End Sub
```

Can you please help me on that? Thanks guys.

Comment: Use the `OpenCurrentDatabase` method and provide the password. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.opencurrentdatabase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
        Private Sub Command35_Click()
        Dim acc As Access.Application
        Dim db As DAO.Database
        Dim strDbName As String
        strDbName = "C:\database Folder\abc.accdb"
        Set acc = New Access.Application
        acc.Visible = False
        acc.OpenCurrentDatabase strDbName, False, "password"
        Set db = acc.CurrentDb() '
        acc.UserControl = True
        acc.DoCmd.RunMacro "Mcr_M_NewFriends"
        acc.Quit
        Me.Command35.BackColor = RGB(255, 124, 128)
        MsgBox "New friends data imported"
   End Sub
```

Comment: The `db` declaration/assignment is pointless - it's not used anywhere in code.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the late answer. I will try it today and let you know.